# How to implement unblock me game with A* algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I want to write a program in java to solve the "unblock me" game for a given state (assume that an initial state of the blocks and the board is given as input), my goal is to give the minimum number of moves that are needed to unblock the red block using A* algorithm.

I was thinking to design a good heuristic for this problem and I came up with manhattan distance witch I think is a good one, but I do not know if there can be better ones. Another problem that I have is that I do not know how to find the possible next state of a given state by coding. I hope that I could get good ideas with your help in this post!

Here is a [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiragames.unblockmefree&hl=en) to the game if you are not familiar :

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
This question is too broad.  Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for a wider variety of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular puzzle is hard for people but not usually hard for computers. So, if you haven't implemented something like this before instead of A*, I'd recommend using a breadth-first search or a depth first search.

BFS: The data structures are relatively easy for a breadth-first search - you can just use a double-ended queue where you remove from the front and add to the back. You may want to check for duplicates, which requires something like a hash table to avoid generating the same state many times.

DFS: For a depth-first search you would use depth-first iterative deepening. That is, you'd limit the DFS to take at most 1 move, then at most 2 moves, etc, until you find the solution. This still guarantees the optimal solution. The only thing you have to do in a DFS is avoid generating moves back to your parent, as this will make the search much less efficient.

Generating moves: To generate moves you consider each piece in the puzzle and the four directions it could possibly move. (up/down/right/left) If the cells next to the piece are all blank, then it can move in that direction. A move is usually defined in a data structure as a piece plus a direction. Typically you can either write a function that returns a list of legal moves, and then you can apply them during the search. If you know the last move, then you can avoid applying the opposite move easily (since it will be the same piece but the opposite direction).

Heuristic: If you want to go with A*, Manhattan distance per piece would work well. If you want something better than that, you can solve the puzzle with 2-3 of the pieces from the puzzle removed and use the solution distance for that simpler puzzle as a heuristic for the full puzzle. But, as I said above, these puzzles are typically so simple that strong heuristics are not needed to solve them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but something is not still clear for me, and that is the "generating moves" part. because there are a lot of states that we can go from one state, and I do not know how to exactly store the states in the fringe, I mean can I assign a specific number to each state and then hash them using a hash function so that I can access them fast?

Comment: @Not_Founded You can build a hash function from the location of each piece in the puzzle if you want to check for duplicates. If there are 10 pieces and each piece can be in one of 10 locations (requires 4 bits), then you can use 40 bits to uniquely hash each state. You only need this for the BFS. In the DFS approach you ignore duplicates, hoping that parent pruning is sufficient. (It should be here.)

Comment: I still do not get it clearly, because each block may have different length, how can we assign a coordinate to each block? what do you mean by bits?

Comment: @Not_Founded You know the size of each block, so you store the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the block. If you don't know what bits are, you'd be best creating a string that describes your state (eg with the coordinates of each block), and then use a built-in function to use the string as a hash.